# Upon shuffling I get a None object. What is wrong?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have shuffled the list and assigned it to another variable and when I am trying to print it, it is giving output as `None`? What is wrong ?

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
list2 = shuffle(list1)
print list2
```

Comment: what does `shuffle` return?  looks like `None`. shuffle changes the list in place, so print `list1` after calling `shuffle`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html?highlight=shuffle#random.shuffle) function is designed to take a list and shuffle its contents. It does not return the shuffled list. The documentation states:

> Shuffle the sequence x in place.

As such, if you try to assign the return to a variable you will get `None`.

You can do the following instead:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
shuffle(list1)
print list1
```

If you wish to preserve your original list order:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
list2 = list1[::]   # make a copy
shuffle(list2)
print list2
```

Answer (score -1):

Shuffle() function is not accessible directly, so we need to import shuffle module and then we need to call this function using random static object.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import random`
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
random.shuffle(list)
print "list : ",  list
```